# Triggering a custom jQuery event without bubbling

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a non-bubblable custom jQuery event on an object. I know we can either use return false or stopPropagation to prevent bubbling. What I want to know is can I trigger a custom event and specify that by default it does not bubble.

This is the code I have now

```
        $(".abc").on("change", function () {
            var e = new $.Event("datachange");
            $(this).trigger(e)
        });
```

The above triggers the datachange event on #abc and bubbles the event all the way up. I don't want that. I can achieve that by using the following.

```
        $(".abc").on("change", function () {
            var e = new $.Event("datachange");
            //e.stopPropagation(); this does not work
            $(this).trigger(e)
        }).on("datachange", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
```

I read that triggerHandler does something similar, but only for the first matching element.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What's so bad about `e.stopPropagation()` in your event handler?

Comment: @crush Its possible that there are no event handlers and the event would end up bubbling and be trapped by a handler not meant for that object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right that [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) only applies to the first element in the set, but that should not be a problem because the set you build with `$(this)` only contains one element.

Therefore, you can safely write:

```
$(".abc").on("change", function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler("datachange");
});
```

That way, the `datachange` event will not bubble up the document tree.